# Как лучше писать переменные

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста как лучше писать переменные

```
<?php echo'',$myrow['username'],' ',$myrow['family'],''?>
```

Или так

```
<?php echo''.$myrow['username'].' '.$myrow['family'].''?>
```

С точками или запятыми?

Comment: зачем вам пустые строки спереди и сзади?

Comment: @IVsevolod зачем вам пустые строки спереди и сзади? В смысле объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: @Andrey Kartavtsev,

> В смысле объясните пожалуйста.

Вот ваш код:

    <?php echo''.$myrow['username'].' '.$myrow['family'].''?>

Можно было вот так написать:

    <?php echo $myrow['username'].' '.$myrow['family']; ?>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

отличия в том, что через точки идет объединение строк, потом вывод. В случае с запятыми сразу идет на вывод кусков. Полностью как вам нравится и согласно стилю разработки проекта.

По скорости запятые быстрее, но даже тысячной доли секунды вы не выиграете.

Comment: @IVsevolod Спасибо большое.